# Find all ideals of quotient ring $\frac{Z[x]}{(x^2+1,5)} $

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Find All ideals of $$\frac{Z[x]}{(x^2+1,5)} $$

---

Attempt]  it would be their intersection , its gcd which is 1. so the only ideals would be $(x^2+1)$ and $(5)$

the wrong approach would be to say that its the combination so the one missing would be $(x^2+6)$

Comment: I think your ring is isomorphic with $\;\left(\Bbb Z_5[x]/\langle x+k\rangle\right)^2\;$ , since $\;x^2+1\;$ is reducible in $\;\Bbb Z_5[x]=\Bbb F_5[x]\;$

Comment: These ideals would be in bijection with ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ which contain $(x^2+1, 5)$.  Now, as a hint, one such ideal which is not immediately obvious would be $(x-2, 5)$ (since then $x^2+1 = (x-2) (x+2) + 5$ would be in this ideal).

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$R=\mathbb{Z}[x]/\left<x^2+1,5\right>\cong\mathbb{Z}_{5}[x]/\left<x^2+1\right>=\mathbb{Z}_{5}[x]/\left<(x+2)(x-2)\right>=\\{}$$

$$=\mathbb{Z}_{5}[x]/\big(\left<x+2\right>\left<x-2\right>\big)\underbrace{=}_{\ast}\mathbb{Z}_{5}[x]/\big(\left<x+2\right>\cap\left<x-2\right>\big)\cong$$

$$\underbrace{\cong}_{\ast\ast}\mathbb{Z}_{5}[x]/\left<x+2\right>\times\mathbb{Z}_{5}[x]/\left<x-2\right>\cong\mathbb{Z}_{5}\times\mathbb{Z}_{5}$$

- Since the ideals $I_{\pm}=\left<x\pm2\right>$ are co-maximal, one can prove that $I_{-}I_{+}=I_{-}\cap I_{+}$ which explains $\ast$.
- The co-maximality also allows us to use CRT to get $\ast\ast$.

Now $\mathbb{Z}_{5}$ is a field, and thus the proper (non-zero) ideals of $R\cong\mathbb{Z}_{5}\times\mathbb{Z}_{5}$ are only

$$\mathbb{Z}_{5}\times0,\:0\times\mathbb{Z}_{5}\triangleleft\mathbb{Z}_{5}\times\mathbb{Z}_{5}$$